# Opera doesn't display special characters from google fonts

Tags: css, opera

I use PT Sans from Google Fonts. It has all the special chars I need (ą, ś, ź, ł etc). The problem is - Opera doesn't display them in bold (in CSS I write `font: bold 16px/2em "PT Sans", sans-serif`, so there is no way it could look for "PT Sans Bold" (but I did include PT Sans both 400 and 700). Firefox, Chrome and IE (8, 9) are doing fine.

What can I do?

edit - live example: http://buszewski.com/opera.html

Comment: @Pekka He probably does if the characters show up as non-bold.

Comment: Are the accented characters shown in not-bold shown in PT Sans 400, or in another font altogether?

Comment: Ohh, so they do work in non-bold, misread that.

Comment: Pekka - I have UTF-8.
millimoose - they doesn't show at all - just blank space.

Comment: Sounds very weird, no idea what this could be. A live example would be cool.

Comment: I've put in on [jsiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yT3TN/) in case your example page doesn't stick around.

Comment: It seems to be working for me in Opera 12 on Mac OS X. What is Opera showing when you do right-click -> "Inspect element"? (Or whatever it's labelled) is it showing the proper characters in the HTML source? Is the browser rendering nothing at all, or a blank space?

Comment: Opera 12.00 on Windows 7 here. I woudn't blame my particular installation, since it's my girlfriend is using it, and she didn't change a thing after fresh install.

Comment: Huh? In Opera 12 on Windows 7 inside the VM, it doesn't seem to be loading the Google font at all for me. That *could* be some VM config issue, although it's weird

Comment: Propably not, since I just checked on my laptop with Opera Next installed. Font isn't loading either.

Comment: Seems like an Opera problem - at http://www.google.com/webfonts/ when you select "PT Sans" and try to write any of the chars I've brought up, it will fail and use normal sans-serif font (Arial for me).

Comment: @Pekka Opera has a number of platform-specific bugs with web fonts bugs; this appears to be another.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Phew, I made it! Actually, solution is pretty simple, all you need to do is add `&subset=latin-ext` at the end of your font link. See [the example](http://jsfiddle.net/yT3TN/1/).